# How to optimize filter JS?

Tags: javascript

There is a following filter code:

```
const foundResult = this.visitors.filter((p: IVisitor) => {
  let found = false;
  if ('qrcode' in this.scanResponse) {
    if (this.scanResponse && p.code && this.scanResponse.qrcode) {
      found = p.code.toLowerCase() === this.scanResponse.qrcode.toLowerCase();
    }
  } else {
    if (this.scanResponse && p.document_number && this.scanResponse.document_number) {
      found = p.document_number.toString().toLowerCase() === this.scanResponse.document_number.toString().toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return found;
});
```

Problem is `this.visitors` contains over 1000 records, so I took a memory screen this operation takes 5 seconds for looking.

How to optimize this filter, any suggestions?

I know that `if` statement is not good in loop, but why it works so long time?

Comment: This piece of code won't take 5 seconds to iterate over just 1000 visitors - at least not under somewhat normal conditions.

Comment: Maybe to use `find`? Seems problem is in another place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there isn't much to optimise in this example without knowing the rest of the app.
I would remove all repeating computations out of the filter. This way:

```js
const checkQR = 'qrcode' in this.scanResponse;
const QR = this.scanResponse && this.scanResponse.qrcode ? this.scanResponse.qrcode.toLowerCase() : null;
const document_number = this.scanResponse && this.scanResponse.document_number ? this.scanResponse.document_number.toString().toLowerCase() : null;

const foundResult = this.visitors.filter((p: IVisitor) => {
  let found = false;
  if (checkQR) {
    found = QR && p.code && p.code.toLowerCase() === QR;
  } else {
    found = document_number && p.document_number && p.document_number.toString().toLowerCase() === document_number;
  }
  return found;
});
```

Other possible techniques depend a lot on your actual code. You could read&filter "visitors" in chunks. You could move this filtering into backend and let the DB do it for you. You could make "visitor" models very tiny containing only `code` and `document_number` and then load only necessary models by filtered IDs from where you get it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the properties from `this` outside of the function to prevent checking an lowering for each cycle.

```
let dn = this.scanResponse && 'document_number' in this.scanResponse && this.scanResponse.document_number.toString().toLowerCase(),
    qrCode = this.scanResponse && this.scanResponse.qrcode.toLowerCase();

const foundResult = this.visitors.filter((p: IVisitor) => {
   return p.code.toLowerCase() === qrcode
       || p.document_number.toString().toLowerCase() === dn;
});
```

Comment: And if that doesn't help "enough", then probably pre-calculating and storing both `p.code.toLowerCase()` and `p.document_number.toString().toLowerCase()` inside the data source upfront should be considered.